# Logstash codec multiline

Tags: logstash, multiline, codec

I'm trying to configure logstash to pull log entries from a honeypot that has multiple lines for each entry. The logs are configured with the following format:

```
 ##############################################
{
    "data": [
        {
            "count": 8,
            "honeypot": "anum",
            "source_ip": "ip1"
        },
        {
            "count": 10,
            "honeypot": "anum",
            "source_ip": "ip2"
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
    ...
    }
}
##############################################
```

Now, can I specify in the pattern part to take the three entries ("count", "honeypot" and "source_ip") and how?

Then, from there can I specify the grok pattern to use the three values?

Answer (score 0):

You can try following config:

```
input {
    stdin {
        codec => multiline {
                pattern => "\#+"
                negate => true
                what => previous
            }
    }
}

filter  {


    if "multiline" in [tags] {
        mutate  {
            gsub => [
                "message", "\n", "",
                "message", "\#", ""
            ]
        }

        json {
            source => "message"
        }

        if  "_jsonparsefailure" not in [tags] {
            split {
               field=>"data" 
            }
        }

    }
}
output {
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

with `split`  filter  you  event will be split by multi event, so  you can reach  the three values as:

```
[data][count]
[data][honeypot]
[data][source_ip]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried your suggestion but logstash is not doing anything. No errors in the log message but no information coming in. Now I'm thinking that it might be a problem with my datafile.